# Access 2010 VBA Type mismatch (Error 13), or Runtime error 424 (Object Required)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am having trouble creating VBA code in Access 2010 to perform 2 actions:

1. If the 3 address lines in my Access Table are `NULL`, or match the city or country name - export them to a separate Excel File for them to be reviewed manually
2. If not, then select one or more address values into a "Address" column in a different Access Table.

This is just trial code, meaning I just want to show I can export values accordingly before I input all `ElseIf` conditions.

- For the code as it is, I'm getting

  > "Type Mismatch" (Error 13) .
- After Googling it seemed I was assigning object/method incorrectly.  If I remove the `""` from the objects I'm referencing I get a different error:

  > "Runtime error 424 (Object Required).

Below is the Code. The first instance of "nmad_address_1" is highlighted after I run it and receive the error.

```
Public Sub EditFinalOutput()

'set loop variable
Dim i As Long
Dim ExportFile As String


'Open Reference Set
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qs = db.OpenRecordset("SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest")
Set ss = db.OpenRecordset("1042s_FinalOutput_6")

'Set loop for entirety of recordset
For i = 0 To qs.RecordCount - 1
    'ExportFile = "I:\Tax Team\Tax Team\Sean" & Format(i, "00") & ".xlsx"

    If qs.Fields(("nmad_address_1" Is Null Or "nmad_address_1" = "nmad_city" 
Or "nmad_address_1" = "Webir_Country") And ("nmad_address_2" Is Null Or 
"nmad_address_2" = "nmad_city" Or "nmad_address_2" = "Webir_Country") And 
("nmad_address_3" Is Null Or "nmad_address_3" = "nmad_city" Or 
"nmad_address_3" = "Webir_Country")) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, 
"SunstarAccountsInWebir_Charlie", "I:\Tax Team\Tax Team\Sean", 1


    Else:   qs.Edit
            qs.Fields("box13c_Address") = 9999
            qs.Update
    End If
    qs.MoveNext
Next i

'Close Reference Set
qs.Close
Set qs = Nothing
ss.Close
Set ss = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Unusual way to loop through a recordset! Better use `Do Until qs.Eof .... qs.MoveNext: Loop` Where `.Eof` means ' End of file'  a property of a recordset that gets true if you move from last element of recordset to the next (not existing),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
If qs.Fields(("nmad_address_1" Is Null Or "nmad_address_1" = "nmad_city" 
Or "nmad_address_1" = "Webir_Country") And ("nmad_address_2" Is Null Or 
"nmad_address_2" = "nmad_city" Or "nmad_address_2" = "Webir_Country") And 
("nmad_address_3" Is Null Or "nmad_address_3" = "nmad_city" Or 
"nmad_address_3" = "Webir_Country")) Then
```

Is nonsense. You're comparing strings to null and constant strings to eachother. You aren't actually comparing any field values. I don't even know which ones are supposed to be field names, and which ones are supposed to be strings.

Also, you do `SomeVar Is Null` in queries. In vba, you do `IsNull(SomeVar)`.

Try the following:

```
With qs.Fields
    If IsNull(!nmad_address_1) Or !nmad_address_1 = "nmad_city" Or !nmad_address_1 = "Webdir_Country" 'etc...
End With
```

Comment: "nmad_address_1", "nmad_address_2", "nmad_address_3", "nmad_city", and "Webir_Country" were columns in the Table - but thank you for identifying my problem.  IS NULL or IS NOT NULL are Boolean types and had to be referenced in a different way (I was referencing them like I would in a Query)